# Dynamically changing <DIV> using jquery fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two simple pages as a test.
The first, PIG_TEST.htm, outputs a simple page containing 3 `<DIV>` sections; Header, Menu and Main.
The Menu section contains a link which, when selected should load the second page, PIG_TEST_1-php, into the `<DIV>` with the id of 'mainx', on the main page via a jquery click function.
However, when selected it just replaces the original page.
Seems like it is not finding or seeing the "mainx" div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'><head>
</head>
<body style='background-color:#eeeecc'>
  <div style='background-color:#6495ed; height: 110px;'>
    <div class='col-md-12 text-center'>Header TEST PAGE
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='background-color:#ffaaaa; height: 150px;'>
    <div class='col-md-12 text-center'>Menu TEST PAGE
      <ul>
        <li><a href='PIG_TEST_1.php' id='but1'>Item 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='mainx' style='background-color:#cccccc; height: 300px;'>
    Main TEST PAGE
  </div>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
(document).ready(function(){
  $('#but1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mainx').load(this.href);
   });
});
</script>
<script src='js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>
</body></html>
```

The PIG_TEST_1.php is:

```
<?php
echo "<body>";
echo "    THIS IS A DUMMY PAGE <br></p>";
echo "</body>";
?>
```

I've tried putting the call to "jquery-1.8.0.min.js" just after the `<body>` but it stll fails.
Sorry, I'm new to jquery, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Load jQuery before you execute jQuery code.

Comment: add your loading jquery script tags to your `<head></head>`

Comment: also `(document)` should be `$(document)`

Comment: @j08691 not necessary.. As its waiting on doc ready right ? So it will be loaded when doc ready..

Comment: @pogrindis `$(document).ready` is a alias to `jQuery(document).ready`.You can't call a function that isn't loaded. If you used plain js docready it might work

Comment: @Austin duhhh of course! Brain fart

Answer (score 2):

You should move the jquery `<script>` tag outside of the other one (you have it nested), and you also need a `$` symbol before `(document).ready`:

```
<script src='js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#but1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mainx').load(this.href);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks @codebox. I moved the call to jquery and added the $ before (document) as suggested and all works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of problems with your code!

1. <strike>`<script>` cannot be contained inside another `<script>` tag.</strike>
2. Load jQuery before calling the function.
3. Add `$` before `(document)`.

So your code should be:

```
<script src='js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#but1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mainx').load(this.href);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Daniel The question was edited. It was nested before.